# SQL: find all rows which have referenced rows that all meet certain conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite

Two tables. One to Many. How to find all companies where absolutely all employees work in IT departments and have salary more than $150000?

```
[COMPANIES]

|----|--------------| 
| id | company_name |
|----|--------------|
| 1  | Google       |
| 2  | Apple        |
|----|--------------| 

[EMPLOYEES]

|----|------------|------|------------|--------|
| id | company_id | name | department | salary |
|----|------------|------|------------|--------|
| 1  | 1          | John | IT         | 200000 |
| 2  | 1          | Bob  | IT         | 200000 |
| 3  | 2          | Rick | Design     | 100000 |
| 4  | 2          | Bill | Design     | 100000 |
|----|------------|------|------------|--------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS` + `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM COMPANIES c
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEES e
    WHERE e.company_id = c.id
     AND  e.salary > 150000 
     AND  e.department = 'IT'
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEES e
   WHERE e.company_id = c.id
     AND  (e.salary <= 150000 OR  e.department <> 'IT')
)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/25c83/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get what you want using a `having` clause:

```
select company_id
from employees
group by company_id
having min(department) = max(department) and
       min(department) = 'IT' and
       min(salary) >= 150000;
```

If you want the company name, you can just join that in:

```
select c.id, c.company_name
from companies c join
     employees e
     on c.id = e.company_id
group by c.id, c.company_name
having min(department) = max(department) and
       min(department) = 'IT' and
       min(salary) >= 150000;
```